# Does x64 support imply BMI1 support?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instruction-set, bmi

It it safe to assume that x64 builds can use [TZCNT](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_tzcnt) without checking its support through cpu flags?

Comment: I'm curious why you even have to ask.  Surely it's easy enough to google BMI1 and see that it was new in Haswell for Intel.  I'm guessing you ran into `tzcnt` not faulting on previous CPUs, or saw a compiler using it without `-mbmi1` or `-march=haswell` and doubted other sources, so I went into detail about that in my answer.  But on the face of it, this question about BMI1 in general could certainly be downvoted for lack of research effort.  (I considered it but didn't.)

Comment: I saw that zlib-ng uses tzcount conditionally at runtime. I wanted to suggest them to always use `bsf` for x86 (they check for 0 anyways) and use tzcnt for x64 builds. But wasn't able to find clear info if all x64 CPUs support it or not.

Comment: If they rule out input=0 already, then they should use `rep bsf` = `tzcnt` *unconditionally* (including 32-bit mode), so it's faster on AMD, same on Intel, at the cost of 1 instruction byte.

Comment: Oh, well it's C not asm so they can't just use `_tzcnt_u32`.  Err wait, that's in an ifdef _MSC_VER so it's never used with compilers that would require `-mbmi1` to be enabled for `_tzcnt_u32`.  So yes, they should use `_tzcnt_u32`.  I'm curious how horrible this is for MSVC when `x86_cpu_has_tzcnt` isn't a compile-time constant.

Comment: It's bad because `x86_cpu_has_tzcnt` isn't compile time constant (if it was, compiler would obviously remove it). It's set at runtime if CPU supports BMI1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, certainly not!  x86-64 was new in late 2003 (AMD K8), with only the legacy `bsf` and `bsr` bit-scan instructions, and none of the rest of BMI1.

The first Intel CPU to support BMI1 was Haswell in 2013.  (Also introducing BMI2.)
The first AMD CPU to support BMI1 was Piledriver in 2012.
[AMD ABM (Advanced Bit Manipulation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#ABM_(Advanced_Bit_Manipulation)) in K10 and later AMD CPUs only added `popcnt` and `lzcnt`, not `tzcnt`.

Wikipedia [Bit Manipulation Instruction Sets: Supporting CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Supporting_CPUs).  Note that Celeron/Pentium branded CPUs don't decode VEX prefixes, so they have AVX and BMI1/BMI2 disabled because BMI1 and 2 each include some VEX-coded instructions like [`andn`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn) and [`blsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr).  This sucks; BMI1/2 are [most useful when compilers can use it everywhere](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=152533&curpostid=152722) throughout an executable for more efficient variable-count shifts, and peepholes, so still selling new CPUs without BMI1/2 is not getting us closer to being able to treat them as baseline like we do for P6 `cmov` in 32-bit mode.

---

#### TZCNT decoding on old CPUs

Since you mention `tzcnt` specifically, its machine-code encoding is `rep bsf` so older CPUs will execute it as BSF.  This produces the same result as `tzcnt` if the input is non-zero.  i.e. **`tzcnt` "works" on all x86 CPUs (since 386) when the input is non-zero.**

But when it is zero, [`tzcnt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tzcnt) would produce the operand-size (e.g. 64), but [`bsf`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf) leaves the destination register unmodified.  `tzcnt` sets FLAGS based on the result, `bsf` based on the input.  AMD documents the dst-unmodified behaviour in their ISA reference manual. Intel only documents it as "undefined value" but implements the same behaviour as AMD, at least in existing CPUs.

(This is why `bsf` / `bsr` have an output dependency on all CPUs, like `add`.  Unfortunately `tzcnt` / `lzcnt` also have a false dependency on Intel Sandybridge-family before Skylake: [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter).  And why `popcnt` does on SnB-family [before Cannon / Ice Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-counter-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance-deviati), because [it shares the same execution unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802692/how-is-popcnt-implemented-in-hardware).)

---

**`tzcnt` is significantly faster on AMD, so compilers tuning for "generic" or AMD CPUs will often use `tzcnt` instead of `bsf` without checking for CPU features.**

e.g. for GNU C `__builtin_ctz`.  That intrinsic has undefined behaviour for input=0 so it's allowed to just use `bsf` without checking for 0.  And thus also allowed to use `tzcnt` because the result in that case is not guaranteed by anything.

[Why does TZCNT work for my Sandy Bridge processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880227/why-does-tzcnt-work-for-my-sandy-bridge-processor)

No such backward / forward compat exists for `lzcnt`.  Having it decode as `rep bsr` with the meaningless `rep` prefix ignored would give you `31 - lzcnt(x)`, the bit-index. https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/bit-scanning-equivalencies/

One handy trick is **`ctz( x | 0x80000000 )`** because OR is cheap<sup>1</sup>, and guarantees there's always a non-zero bit for `bsf` to find.  It doesn't change the result for any non-zero `x` because it's the last bit `bsf` will look at.  This trick also works for `__builtin_clz(x|1)` / `bsr`, where it's even better because `or reg, imm8` is even shorter than `imm32`.

Footnote 1: `or reg, imm32` works for a 32-bit constant; `bts reg,63` is less cheap on some CPUs to implement `x|(1ULL<<63)` for a 64-bit input.