# Clearing all starting ASCII 0's from a string in x64 NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to remove all of the `'0'`s from the beginning of a string in NASM.

```
mov ecx, "0001"  ; ecx now holds 0x31303030
-> code that clears the first 3 zeros so that ecx will hoad 0x31 only
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: ECX is always 32 bits wide.  What do you want in the rest of the register, once you get `0x31` into the low byte?

Comment: This looks unusual.  Most of the time when manipulating strings, they are in memory, not in a register.  And the simplest way to remove leading zeros from a string in memory is just to return a pointer to the first non-zero character and work with that pointer as a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `cl` - if it doesn't equal `'0'` you're done, otherwise shift `ecx` one byte to the right and repeat.

```
remove_zeroes:
    cmp cl,'0'
    jne done
    shr ecx,8
    jmp remove_zeroes
done:
```

If you can spare another register, this could be improved a bit:

```
remove_zeroes:
    mov eax,ecx
    shr ecx,8
    cmp al,'0'
    je remove_zeroes
mov ecx,eax
```

Comment: That's one option, but pretty inefficient.  You could put the cmp/jne at the bottom, if you put a branch outside the loop to check if SHR should run even once.

Comment: BTW, I posted an answer with a loop that checks once before falling into a do{}while loop, so you don't need a spare register, and don't do a wasted `shr` on the last iteration.  Costs a little bit of extra code-size, but fewer instructions actually executed for any given input.  Your way is ok if optimizing purely for code-size, my way is what a normal compiler like `gcc -O2` would do.

Comment: @PeterCordes GCC (10.3) does generate the variant with an initial check before the loop. Clang (12.0.0) generates the variant with two registers and no initial check.

Comment: Fair enough, interesting choice.  https://godbolt.org/z/5PnnboKaP. I guess it could be worth saving a bit of L1i cache space and uop-cache space (and space in the binary) that way, but I still think it's most likely a missed optimization.  I'm curious if this was intentional by clang devs after comparing tuning choices, or if it's a side-effect of their optimizer that they haven't looked at one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the high bytes to be `0` (not `'0'`) when you're done, @Michael's loop will work even the 2nd one isn't quite as efficient as it could be.  See [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump) for standard efficient loop structure, i.e. peeling the compare/branch part of the first iteration so we can rotate the loop.

```
    cmp  cl, '0'
    jne  .done           ; low byte already not ASCII '0'
 .remove_zeros:
    shr  ecx,8
    cmp  cl,'0'
    je   .remove_zeros
 .done:
```

---

**There are other interesting things you could do: branchless non-looping**

For example using `ctz(ecx ^ '0000')` to get the position of the first bit-difference (counting from the bottom of the register), then rounding it down to a multiple of 8 bits as a shift count.  Handling the case where all 4 bytes are `'0'` requires some care because it requires a shift-count of 32, but [BSF](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf) can't produce that, and 32-bit shifts mask the count so it would wrap.

However, implementing `ctz` as [TZCNT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tzcnt) *will* produce 32 for an all-zero input, and a 64-bit operand-size for the shift will let it work, making with `&63` instead of `&31`.  ([`shr` docs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr))

```
   mov   eax, ecx
   xor   ecx, '0000'                   ; or '000' to always keep the highest byte
     ; jz  special_case_all_zero       ; optional
   tzcnt ecx, ecx                  ; decodes as BSF on older CPUs, which is ok for non-zero ECX
   and   ecx, -8                   ; clear low 3 bits = round down to multiple of 8
   shr   rax, cl                   ; 64-bit shift lets count=32 work
; result in EAX

   ;mov   ecx, eax           ; if you need the result back in ECX
```

For example, with ECX = '0040' (0x30343030)

```
'0040' ^ '0000' = '0040' (0x00040000)
BSF / TZCNT = 18  
18 & -8 = 16  
0x30343030 >> 16 = 0x00003034 = '40' (zero-extended in a dword)
```

**With the ECX = '0000' special case**, we get TZCNT(0) = 32.  But on an older CPU that decodes TZCNT as BSF (ignoring the REP prefix), it leaves the destination unmodified, so we get 0.  (dst-unmodified behaviour is documented by AMD, but implemented by both Intel and AMD on their current CPUs at least.)

**All-zero is a special-case anyway if you want to reduce it to `'0'` instead of the empty string, though.**  You might do that without extra branching by doing **`xor ecx, '000'`** (3 ASCII 0s with a binary 0 as the high byte).  The only way you can shift by 32 is when the high byte was already `0` (not `'0'`).  i.e. it will keep any non-zero high byte.

If you don't need TZCNT to produce 32 for an all-zero register, that makes it ok for it to [decode as BSF on CPUs without BMI1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880227/why-does-tzcnt-work-for-my-sandy-bridge-processor); see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422827/does-x64-support-imply-bmi1-support).  So this code will work correctly on any x86-64 CPU despite being written with a BMI1 instruction.  And ok to use `shr eax, cl` instead of `rax`, saving the REX prefix.

---

Note, it's called TZCNT because the low bits of a register are the "trailing" bits.  But x86 is little-endian, so when dealing with strings, the first byte in printing order (lowest memory address) is the *highest* 8 bits of the integer value.  The naming of BSF (bit scan forwards) does follow little-endian, though.

**Picking any other input register would be more convenient** for your ASCII data so it could stay in that register while we generate the shift count in ECX.  Unless you have BMI2, then you could use `shrx ecx, ecx, eax` for example to do `ecx >>= eax`.  It's also more efficient; only a single uop even on Intel CPU, where `shr reg, cl` is 3 because of legacy x86 baggage (FLAGS has to remain unmodified if the count is 0).  https://uops.info/ / https://agner.org/optimize/

---

You could also do this with SIMD `pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` / `not eax` with `'0000'` in xmm1.  That gives you a byte-compare mask (like the XOR bit-compare mask), which you can bit-scan and scale by 8 to turn into a shift count.  But that's not better vs. XOR; only seems useful if you were going to do something with SIMD shuffles to handle 16 bytes at once.

(There's no variable-count SIMD byte-shift, but maybe you could use the bit-scan result to load a sliding window from an array of `db 0, 1, ..., 14, 15` / `times 16 db -1` to get a shuffle control vector for `pshufb`.)

Or use the `pcmpeqb` / `movd eax, xmm0` result for BMI2 `pext`, except that will remove all zeros, not just the low ones.  To set all the bits above the lowest 1, maybe `blsi` to isolate the low bit, then `neg`?  That's probably more instructions and higher latency than using XOR / TZCNT / AND to get a shift count, and shifts are lower latency than PEXT even on Intel CPUs where it's 1 uop / 3c latency.  (vs. being very slow and microcoded on AMD).

AVX-512VBMI2 ([Ice Lake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/ice_lake_(client)#New_instructions)) for [`vpcompressb xmm1{k1}{z}, xmm2`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPCOMPRESS) with a mask from [AVX-512BW `vpcmpb k, xmm, xmm/m128, _MM_CMPINT_EQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpcmpb:vpcmpub) would have the same problem of removing all zeros.